# existence of package to customize section

Tags: sectioning

I'm asking if does it exist a package to customize section or subsection as `fncychap` is used to customize chapter. I would have my section more fancy maybe adding some hrule or some decorations.

Comment: I didn't find any examples...can you provide me something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are taken from the user manual of `titlesec` (See Appendix, page 19)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\titleformat{\section}[frame]
{\normalfont}
{\filright
\footnotesize
\enspace SECTION \thesection\enspace}
{8pt}
{\Large\bfseries\filcenter}
%This can be used for chapters also
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\Large\filcenter\sffamily}
{\titlerule[1pt]%
\vspace{1pt}%
\titlerule
\vspace{1pc}%
\LARGE\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}
{1pc}
{\titlerule
\vspace{1pc}%
\Huge}
\begin{document}
\chapter{My chapter}
\lipsum[3]
\section{My section}
\lipsum[1-2]
%
\titleformat{\section}
{\titlerule
\vspace{.8ex}%
\normalfont\itshape}
{\thesection.}{.5em}{}
\section{My another section}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]